# Phase estimation in the book Quantum Computation and Quantum Information

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

This question is about a derivation in section 5.2.1 of the book Quantum Computation and Quantum Information by Nielsen & Chuang. More specifically the derivation of the equation (5.27). This equation gives a probability of obtaining value $m$ such that $\mid m-b\mid > e$, or in symbols:

$$p(\mid m-b\mid > e) = \sum_{-2^{t-1}<l'\leq -(e+1)}|\alpha_{l'}|^2+\sum_{e+1\leq l'\leq 2^{t-1}}|\alpha_{l'}|^2$$

I reasoned as follows: write $l=l'+b \:\mathrm{mod} \:2^t$ in the vector (5.23), then select all the amplitudes such that $|l'|>e$. Then the index sets that I get in the sum above are $-2^{t}+1\leq l'\leq -(e+1)$ and $e+1\leq l'\leq 2^{t}-1$, but it differs from result in the book. What am I missing?